# HABTM find with a condition

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables which are related as HABTM:

- Groups(id, name)
- Streams(id, Stream)

Connecting table:

- groups_streams(id, group_id, stream_id)

There is another model called Users which HasOne Group.

From the User controller I am trying to get the streams related to the User's Group.

```
$streams = $this->User->Group->find('list', array('conditions' => array(`User.group_id` => 2)));
```

I am doing this, but I'm getting a MySQL error:

> SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 2' at line 1

SQL Query:

```
SELECT `Group`.`id` FROM `groups` AS `Group` WHERE = 2
```

I'm confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather go with:

```
$streams = $this->Stream->Group->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Group.id => 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `User.group_id` in quotes within your `'conditions'` array:

```
$streams = $this->User->Group->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.group_id' => 2)
));
```